# From table to multi-level tree

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have exported a structure from a software (Schema ST4), but the export file only shows a linear table with chapters level shown as columns:[Output HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDATD.jpg)

I would rather like to have the structure shown as in the original navigation tree:[Original navigation tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2P19.jpg)

Would there be a way to transform the HTML I got (see below) in order to make it look as in the original navigation tree ? Is there a GUI software that would make it easily ? I am indeed very new to XSLT and it would take me too much time to do this in regard to the goal.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Doc navigation tree</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pl_export.css" type="text/css"><body>
<div class="comment">Doc navigation tree exported by iSDocViewer v5.10.0.0</div>
<div class="comment">Instrument</div>
<div class="comment">Doc version: 1.0</div>
<div class="comment">Date, Time: 1/7/2019 3:24:39 PM</div>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Navigation L1</th>
<th>Navigation L2</th>
<th>Navigation L3</th>
<th>Navigation L4</th>
<th>Navigation L5</th>
<th>Document title</th><tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Service documentation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>About this documentation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>About this product</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Training</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Trademarks</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Contact</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Preface</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Feedback</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Revisions</td><td>Service documentation</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Version 1.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Revisions</td><td>Service documentation</td><td>Revision history</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Version 0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Safety</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Introduction</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Safety</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>About safety classifications</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Safety</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>About additional information</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Safety</td><td>List of WARNING messages</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>About biohazardous material</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preface, revisions, and safety</td><td>Safety</td><td>List of WARNING messages</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>About chemical reaction producing toxic gas</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks a lot in advance and have a great day !

Kind regards.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect to get here? Is it possible? Yes. Is there a GUI software that would make it easy? Don't know, probably not.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping that a GUI software would allow to define sublevels from the table.
I will try to find documentation on XSLT to make it then !

Comment: Ok finally I would like to get advices on which XSLT functions should be used with that "column = level" table logics.

Comment: Ok now the more precise question is: how to find elements in column 3 for example, find their parents, and then order them in a menu according to their parents and children found ?